# Does anyone know this Zohar term used in the Shemiras HaLashon?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, chofetz-chaim

There’s a phrase in the Sefer Shemiras HaLashon by the Chofetz Chaim that I can’t seem to recall or find. It was a term from Kabbalah that, if I recall correctly, spoke about the punishment for a soul in the next world - I think it had to do with being stretched out perhaps? Does anyone recall seeing this phrase?

Note 1: it’s not the term Sachsucha he brings down from the Zohar

Note 2: I seem to also recall a MY question about this phrase but have been searching and haven’t found it.

Comment: This? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16396/what-is-the-kaf-hakelah

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yes! I think that was it! So quick! Any chance you know where it was appears in the Sefer? (And thank you so so much)

Comment: It's quoted [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemirat_HaLashon%2C_Book_I%2C_The_Gate_of_Remembering.9.5?lang=bi) from the Gra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your comment, I can confirm you are referring to the כף הקלע, which is explained in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16396/what-is-the-kaf-hakelah).

In this question, you are asking for the source in the Zohar.

It is based on [Shmuel 1:25:29](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.25.29?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> וַיָּקָם אָדָם לִרְדָפְךָ וּלְבַקֵּשׁ אֶת־נַפְשֶׁךָ וְהָיְתָה נֶפֶשׁ
> אֲדֹנִי צְרוּרָה  בִּצְרוֹר הַחַיִּים אֵת יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ וְאֵת
> נֶפֶשׁ אֹיְבֶיךָ יְקַלְּעֶנָּה בְּתוֹךְ **כַּף הַקָּלַע׃**
>
> Though a man rises to pursue thee, and to seek thy soul: yet the soul
> of my lord shall be bound in the bond of life with the Lord thy God;
> and the souls of thy enemies, them shall he sling out, as out of the
> **hollow of a sling**.

It is discussed in the Zohar in several places including

- [Mishpatim 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Mishpatim.3.104?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Beshalach 23](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Beshalach.23.321?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Terumah 29](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Terumah.29.299?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Vayikra 64](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayikra.64.425?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Balak 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Balak.4.24?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Vayera 17](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayera.17.243?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Pinchas 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Pinchas.4.14?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)
- [Vayechi 19](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayechi.19.141?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&qh=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2)

As well as [many other places throughout Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9B%D7%A3%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%A2&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @user I hate it when I forget something like this, glad to have helped