# כף הקלע while alive?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

I saw this in the Piasezno Rebbe's Hachsharat Avrechim:

> וכבר אמרו חז״ל [בר״ר פל״ד] הצדיקים לבן ברשותן ולהיפך ח״ו, הם ברשות
> לבן. ובזה תלוי הכל, מי שלגמרי הוא ברשות לבו ואינו יכול להתגבר גם על
> תאוותיו לגמרי ח״ו, אז רשע הוא, אבל גם אותם יקרי רוח בחורי חמד ואברכים
> חסידים [חסידישע יונגעליוט] שבענינו התאוה אינם ברשות לבם ח״ו, לוחמים הם
> עם יצרם ומתגברים במלחמתם לבלי נפול ברשותו לעבור עבירה בפועל ח״ו, ועוד
> העיר ד׳ את רוחו עליהם שירצו להיות חסידים אף מתרגשים לפעמים מעצמם, גם
> הם אם לא יהיו גם בזה לבם ברשותם שיוכלו לעורר את עצמם כשיעלה בהמחשבתם,
> ויוכלו להתרגש בשעה שידעו שצריכים להתרגש, גם אלו לא יגיעו אל שום עלי׳
> אף לא אל עקבי החסידות, וגם הם ח״ו יכולים להיות קלועים **בכף הקלע**
> הנ״ל. לכן מתחננים אנו בזה מד׳ שיזכנו לראות ולהראות את האופנים איך יוכל
> האיש להיות גם בענין הזה בידו, שיעורר את רצונו שהוא רצון הנפש כמ״ש
> זוה״ק הנ״ל, בשעה שיעלה במחשבתו, ולהתרגש בשעה שידע שצריך להתרגש,
> ומובטחני בד׳ אלקי ישראל המאיר את לבותם, והולך לפניהם תמיד בעמוד אש
> להאיר להם את הדרך דרך ד׳ ללכת בו אליו יומם ולילה, שכאשר יעלה בידנו לתת
> להאיש אופן ואמצעי איך יוכל ברצונו לזעזע את נפשו גם זעזוע מעטת, אף
> לזעזע קצוות נוצותי׳ בבחירתו, אז בעקבות החסידות ילך, ולא ישאר במצבו זה
> לבד אלא גם אל פסגת רומה יגיע ואל היכל ד׳ עם קדושיו אל הג״ע אשר בארץ
> יגיע.
>
> The sages teach us (Bereishis Rabba, 34), “Tsaddikim are in possession
> of their hearts.” With the converse, God protect us, we see that that
> their hearts posses them. Everything depends on this. Someone whose
> heart possesses him and can not completely control his desires is
> called a “rasha” (evil one). But still, there are precious souls,
> sweet young men, “Chasidishe Yungelait,” (newly married Chassidic
> yeshiva students) who have worldly desires and are, “not in possession
> of their hearts.” But they do battle with their evil inclinations and
> emerge victorious in that they do not actually fall into sin, God
> forbid. Furthermore, God sends them an awakening of the divine soul
> within them and they yearn to be Chasidim, and then at times they
> bring about the arousal to avodas Hashem. And yet, if they are not in
> possession of their hearts to the point when they can will the arousal
> at the time when the thought arises, if they cannot feel excitement at
> a time when such excitement is warranted, then even they will not
> reach any great level even if they follow the path of Chasidus. Such
> students could also be “**caught in the sling**” of the erratic
> religious personality who wavers in his dedication to serving God with
> soul. Therefore we beg Hashem to allow us to see and to show the
> angels how man can also have the ability to arouse his desire which
> then awakens the soul, as the Zohar teaches us. Master of the World!
> Let us be able to will the arousal at the time when the thought
> arises, and to feel excitement at a time when such excitement is
> warranted. I promise you, in the name of the God of Israel Who
> illuminates their souls, and goes ever before them in a pillar of fire
> to light His own way so that they may travel by it day and night, that
> when we provide man with the path and the means with which to
> willingly shake his soul even in the slightest, even as little as the
> decision to shake the tips of her feathers, then the student will
> truly be able to follow the path of Chassidus. Then he will not only
> remain in this state, but even reach the pinnacle of avodas Hashem,
> arriving at God’s heavenly chamber with its holy ones, making the
> Garden of Eden here on earth.
>
> (Translation by Betzalel Edwards)

I have never heard of the concept of a כף הקלע while alive. Is this the Rebbe being his trademark poetic self (the "benoni" riding the wave of crecendoing service followed by being drawn after worldly temptations and sinking - it does sound like a good mashal for the [spiritual כף הקלע](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/137511/31534)), or is this a thing? Discussed in what sources?

Comment: Glad you're diving into Hachsharas Avrechim @RabbiKaii!! :-)

Comment: What makes you think it is a reference to when they are alive? Could it not be that, if they continue to practice such behaviour, it will result in the punishment of Kaf HaKelah?

Comment: @Dov I suppose that's a third possibility that didn't occur to me, but I find it harder to read into the words than my two suggestions. Thanks for recommending the sefer, it's pure gold

Comment: Most sifrei kabbalah are pretty definitive that it is very much after death - e.g. See Rav Chaim Vital's Shaarei Kedusha - https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'arei_Kedusha%2C_Part_2.5.15?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en

Comment: @Dov my line of thinking was something like "we have rectification down here as well as up here, and perhaps they reflect each other to some degree". It would be nice to see this as a known "earthly mashal" for the real thing and learn some lessons about it if there are any. Thanks for the source